# Unable to reference BCrypt File from JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to encrypt my password prior to storing in my remote database but I get an error saying

> "Classes from the default package must not be referenced from JSP
>   file"

Where else should I reference it? I am having BCrypt as a jar file in my lib folder.

```
//Code at JSP file

    <html>
        <body>
            <%
                //This line causes error
                String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());
            %>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your class to the package.

The JSP page is compiled into a class that is placed in the package. Classes that are in packages, can't import classes that are in the default package.